# How can I create webpack package of SharePoint online for react App?

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, spfx, spfx-tooling, react

I can create package of react app for SharePoint online by using "gulp serve" and "gulp package-solution" commands. However, I want to create package by using Webpack. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why do you need it? Normally you shouldn't use webpack directly in SPFx, everything is handled by SPFx build pipeline internally.

Comment: To implement tree shaking and features of webpack..

Answer (score 0):

You can't create an SPFx package using webpack directly, however you have options to modify webpack configuration which is used by SPFx build pipeline internally.

Good reading here - [Extending Webpack in the SharePoint Framework toolchain](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/toolchain/extending-webpack-in-build-pipeline).
So theoretically you are able to modify some settings inside a webpack pipeline.
However, consider a few gotchas:

- SPFx still uses webpack 3, thus you should use tree shaking features of webpack 3 (which are probably don't work as good as in 4.x version)
- I'm not sure if in general, it's a good idea to change production-related settings for SPFx. From my perspective, it might lead to unexpected errors. Unfortunately, Microsoft doesn't provide clear information on this topic.